# What do I need to set up a short-term wireless link between buildings?

Tags: wireless-networking

I currently have a leased line in one building. I intend to move to a building with line-of-sight less than 100m away.

What equipment would I need to set up a radio/laser link between the buildings while I am getting the leased line transferred to the new building?

Comment: Will you be keeping access to the (part of the) building that you are currently using? (I.e., will not transferring the leased line present any difficulties with e.g. equipment placement?)

Comment: It's a short-term solution until we can get the leased line transferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options come to mind.

**Inexpensive**

Sounds crazy, but if it is only 100 meters away, you could run outdoor cat5 cable between buildings for a few weeks.

**Proper Solution**

A more expensive solution, yet correct solution would be to setup a wireless bridge between the buildings.

You will need
- Two wireless Access Points / Bridges
- Two directional antennas

I recommend you take a look at Ubiquiti's AirMax line of products. I've had excellent success using the ubiquity [bullet](http://www.ubnt.com/airmax#bulletm), and the [nanoBridge](http://www.ubnt.com/airmax#nanobridgem).

Simply turn them on, navigate to their statically assigned ip addresses, set them to bridged mode, and point them at each other in phase. Even several hundred feet away, I can get over 100mbps.

For added security, turn broadcasting off, and use a strong encryption key.

http://www.ubnt.com/airmax

Update:
As mentioned in the comments, outdoor wireless has additional variables to consider:

- Rain / Fog : It is a [myth](http://gizmodo.com/5629814/giz-explains-why-everything-wireless-is-24ghz) that 2.4ghz is the optimal resonating frequency of water.

According to the Cisco Wireless Certification Study guide:

> Visual line of sight is not needed as long as you have RF line of
>   sight. You may not be able to see the antenna due to fog, but the fog
>   will not prevent RF line of sight.

Additionally

> Conditions such as rain, snow, and fog present two unique challenges.
>   First, all out- door equipment must be protected from damage from
>   exposure to water. Water damage is often a serious problem with
>   cabling and connectors. Connectors should be protected with drip loops
>   and coax seal to prevent water damage. Cables and connectors should be
>   checked on a regular basis for damage. A radome should be used to
>   protect antennas from water dam- age. Outdoor bridges, access points,
>   and mesh routers should be protected from the weather elements using
>   appropriate National Electrical Manufacturers Association (NEMA)
>   enclosure units. Precipitation can also cause an RF signal to
>   attenuate. A torrential downpour can atten- uate a signal as much as
>   .08 dB per mile (.05 dB per kilometer) in both the 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz
>   frequency ranges. Over long-distance bridge links, a system operating
>   margin (SOM) of 20 dB is usually recommended to compensate for
>   attenuation due to rain or fog or snow.

- Lightning

To protect your equipment you should additionally invest in lightning arresters.

Comment: I agree. outdoor cat5E is crazy. At least use something which does not conduct electricity (e.g. fibre). And if this crosses a road you might need a license.  As to wireless, please make sure you get something which works in all weather conditions. (This includes foggy weather)

Comment: I don't think it'll be possible to mount the equipment outdoor. Would running through windows degrade signals much? The buildings aren't parallel, and one will be higher than the other.

Comment: @Gerry at 2.4ghz you can expect to see a -3 db degradation in signal. (If you are only going 100m, that won't make a big difference). If possible, place the antenna perpendicular to the glass to avoid signal deflections. It won't matter if one is higher than the other, as long as they are pointed directly at each other.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a WiFi router with external antenna feed, and a WiFi extender (a model with one external antenna feed). The WiFi router needs to be plugged into the existing line, and the signal will be boosted by the WiFi extender at the other end, 100m away.

Depending on the environmental EM noise level, they might work satisfactorily just like that. If they don't, you will be able to replace/add a pair of directional high-gain WiFi antennas (IP-67 external versions exist) to further boost the signal. The directionality and boost factor of the antennas depend on their cost, and you should be able to estimate how much beer the antenna needs from the behaviour in antenna-less configuration: i.e., if you have *almost tolerable* service level with bundled antennas, don't bother spending US$ 100 for a pair of high-gain long-range directional antennas; it's likely that a US$ 18 pair of high gain antennas will be enough to boost performance back into suitability.

(You can also run a WiFi scan of the environment beforehand, to assess how many transmitters are there competing for ether).

On the other hand, if you get *no* signal at all line-of-sight notwithstanding, this would mean there's a terrifying amount of EM noise, and you'll have to think about a couple of cantennas or even long-range parabolic antennas. But that should be unlikely in any reasonable neighbourhood.